# Does gradle use mirror settings in .m2/settings.xml

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

Does gradle use mirror settings in `~/.m2/settings.xml`?
We have a `<mirror>` pointing to artifacts from ProjectA.
We don't want to point to the same mirror for ProjectB.

Does ProjectB specific artifacts get resolved via that `<mirror>`, if so how should we prevent this?

Comment: As far as i know gradle has it's own folder `${HOME}/.gradle/gradle.init`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know `~/.m2/settings.xml` is only consulted to find the location of the local maven repository (`mavenLocal()` in Gradle).

So to answer your question:

> Does gradle use mirror settings in ~/.m2/settings.xml?

No, it does not. Gradle not only has it's own way to define [repository locations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html), it is also possible to specify multiple locations within the `repositories { }` configuration.

Comment: This makes the gradle build scripts dependent on the concrete maven repository URL's. I do not like this.